# SQL Nested join showing the current price of each product and using MAX()

Tags: sql, join, group-by, db2, ibm-cloud

What is the current price of  each product?  Display product code, product description, unit, and its current price.
HINT:  You will use MAX(). This is a nested join.

**PRODUCT TABLE**

*prodCode*

description

unit

**PRICE HIST**

*effDate*

*prodCode*

unitPrice

Can someone help me to improve my script ?

this is my script, im using ibm.cloud

```
SELECT p.prodCode, p.description, p.unit, MAX(ph.unitPrice) "Current Price"
FROM product p 
FULL  JOIN  priceHist ph
ON   p.prodCode = ph.prodCode
GROUP BY p.prodCode, p.description, p.unit 
ORDER BY MAX (ph.unitPrice);
```

Comment: You are defining the current price as the highest unit price for a product in the priceHistory table? It seems like that assumption would break if the price ever went down. I would think the current price would be based on the date on which the price was published into priceHistory.

Comment: my priceHist has effDate(effective date.)

Comment: Im done editing, can u help me to improve my answer ?

Comment: You may use `priceHist` twice to get `unitPrice` for max `effDate` for each `prodCode`: first you group by `prodCode` and use `max(effDate) as effDate`, and join the result to the same `priceHist` by these 2 columns. Try to write such a join on your own. It's easy to write a final statement joining  `product` afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you each product and its latest price in a table.

```
SELECT p.prodCode, p.description, p.unit,
       (SELECT unitPrice
        FROM priceHist
        WHERE prodCode = p.prodCode
        ORDER BY effDate DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) "Current Price"
FROM product p;
```

Comment: what if no WHERE script ? we will use 2 priceHist ?

Answer (score 0):

I think full join is not required (use `left join`) and you can use the `where` clause as follows:

```
SELECT p.prodCode, p.description, p.unit, coalesce(ph.unitPrice,p.unitprice)  "Current Price"
FROM product p 
Left JOIN  priceHist ph ON p.prodCode = ph.prodCode
WHERE ph.prodcode is null
   or ph.date_col = (select max(phh.date_col) from pricehist phh on phh.prodcode = ph.prodcode)
```

Comment: what if no WHERE script ? we will use 2 priceHist ?

Answer (score 0):

In DB2, I would recommend window functions:

```
SELECT p.prodCode, p.description, p.unit, ph.unitPrice as current_price
FROM product p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ph.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prodCode ORDER BY effdate) as seqnum
      FROM priceHist ph
     ) ph
     ON ph.prodCode = p.prodCode AND ph.seqnum = 1
ORDER BY ph.unitPrice;
```

Comment: what if no WHERE script ? we will use 2 priceHist ?

Comment: @HiImnewb . . . I have no idea what you mean in your comment.  The filtering is in the `on` clause.